# JQuery.load isn't even running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working, but I have a `JQuery.load` with the below code:

```
var modcode = $(this).attr('data-modcode');
var link = $(this).attr('href');
$('#subUnitWrapper').append('<div id="h' + modcode + '"></div>');
$('#h' + modcode).load(link + ' #divMiddle h4', function(data){
    debugger;
    $('#h' + modcode).append(data);
});
```

I've run it through a `debugger` statement, and it's getting the link fine, same goes for the element append. But when I put a `debugger` statement inside the load function, it didn't even hit it. The link is relative, but I don't see how that could affect it.

Comment: what the value ur getting in "modcode" variabel

Comment: @srinivas an example would be `123456.01`

Comment: Search for "how do I debug ajax requests?"

Comment: try to use static id once and check its problem with load function or dynamic id function .